# jquery panel widget won't open internal page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to open panel widget with a list in it.

in html document i have 3 internal pages, index, holzart, qualitat. after loading the page and selecting a ex. holzart the internal page won't show up. the same things happen with the other page. also what i noticed is that i cannot sometimes open the hole panel. i am watching the chrome debug window and there are no errors in it. i am appreciate any suggestions. Here is the full code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<!--index page-->
<div data-role="page" id="index" data-title="Start" data-url="index">

    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Lager</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <!-- content -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Lager</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->



<!--holzart page-->
<div data-role="page" id="#holzart" data-title="Holzart">
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Lager</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
        <!--<script src="js/holzart.js"></script>-->
        <h1>Neue Holzart eingeben - Alle holzarten ansehen</h1>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle">
                <form id="form_holzart" action="php/holzart_ins.php" method="post">
                    <label for="holzart">Neue Holzart eingeben:</label>
                    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="holzart_txt" id="holzart_txt">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"  width="50%">
                <form>
                    <input type="button" id="speichern" name="speichern" value="Speichern">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td align="center"  width="50%">
                <form>
                    <input type="button" id="loschen" name="loschen" value="Eingabe löschen">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle"><div id="message"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!--list populated from js and php-->
    <div>
        <ul id="holzart_h" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--list populated from js and php-->

    <!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Lager</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

</div>
<!--end of holzart page  -->

<!--qualitat page-->
<div data-role="page" id="#qualitat" data-title="Qualität">
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Lager</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
        <!--<script src="js/holzart.js"></script>-->
        <h1>Neue Qualität eingeben - Alle Qualiteten ansehen</h1>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle">
                <form id="form_qualitat" action="php/qualitat_ins.php" method="post">
                    <label for="qualitat">Neue Qualität eingeben:</label>
                    <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="qualitat_txt" id="qualitat_txt">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"  width="50%">
                <form>
                    <input type="button" id="speichern_q" name="speichern_q" value="Speichern">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td align="center"  width="50%">
                <form>
                    <input type="button" id="loschen_q" name="loschen_q" value="Eingabe löschen">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle"><div id="message_q"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!--list populated from js and php-->
    <div>
        <ul id="qualitat_q" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--list populated from js and php-->

    <!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Lager</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

</div>
<!--end of qualitat page  -->


</div>
<!--end of index page  -->


    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Schließen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#index">Zum start</a></li>
            <li><a href="#holzart">Holzart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#starke">Stärke</a></li>
            <li><a href="#qualitat">Qualität</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lange">Länge</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reihe">Reihe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#platz">Platz</a></li>
            <li><a href="#strasse">Straße</a></li>
            <li><a href="#seite">Seite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#grosse_des_pakets">Große des pakets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#neuer_paket_anlegen">Neuer paket anlegen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#suchen">Suchen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menge_nach">Menge nach...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel --> 






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For better answers, check [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry to say but the titel is describing the problem and i give all the code that creates problems. try it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the panel at the top of the page.

Initialize the panel in script:

```
$(function () {
    $("body>[data-role='panel']").panel().find("ul").listview();
});
```

Remove the "#" from the page ids in the markup

```
<div data-role="page" id="#holzart" data-title="Holzart">
```

should be

```
<div data-role="page" id="holzart" data-title="Holzart">
```

Add closing `</DIV>` to your index page and the content divs within the pages. Right now you have the other 2 pages within index.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/p5jwrbke/)**